# REST + SSH transport?

Tags: rest, ssh, jersey

I'm new to REST Web Services. SSH is transport layer encryption, right? So if I need a protocol for communicating securely, is there any reason why I can't use this + JSON? Is it:

1. Possible?
2. OK, i.e. there's no holes or blockers, like "you could but you shouldn't" or "there's an easier way to accomplish transport layer encryption." or "there's actually no libraries for it", etc. etc.
3. Any examples?

What I'm familiar with is Jersey but I'm OK with CXF.

Comment: Why SSH and not SSL (aka HTTPS)?

Comment: Right. Now I remember. We have to do it a certain way because the remote agency requires it. SSH wont do either, actually, but I'm still curious, as it would be awesome. :-)

Comment: Take a look at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/31226/1554.

Comment: Well I do know now to do an SSH tunnel. Is the implication that it cannot be done as part of the service?  Maybe I don't want my application dependant on the existence of an external SSH server.  ...or perhaps, an update of the local SSH server shouldn't impact production.